Angular Animation to child elements doesn't work
I can't find why the animation is not working. I would like to animate it so that each child element would ease in, staggered.
const fadeInStagger = trigger('fadeInStagger', [
  transition('* => *', [
    query(':enter', [
      style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(-20px)' }),
      stagger('200ms', [
        style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(-20px)' }),
        animate('1s ease-in', style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateY(0)' }))
      ])
    ], { optional: true })
  ])
]);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, RouterLink],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  animations: [fadeInStagger],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  stateService = inject(StateService);

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.stateService.resetState();
    localStorage.clear();
  }
}


<div @fadeInStagger class="my-10 flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-6">
    <h1 class="">Welcome!</h1>
    <p class="subtitle">Click on the button below to start the challenge!</p>
    <div class="mt-2">
        <a [routerLink]="['/captcha']" class="home-button btn text-lg">Start</a>
    </div>
</div>


Your transition should be enter :
transition(':enter', ...)

Because your container element (the div) is entering the view.
The * state does NOT include the void state, and since :enter is equivalent to void => *, your animation is not concerned.
Next, you should query any child element :
query(':self > *', ...)
// If it does not work with :self
query('> *', ...)
// If it does not work with direct children selector
query('h1,.mt-2,p', ...)

Finally, your stagger does not need to apply the style first, since your already did it just above
stagger('200ms', [
  animate('1s ease-in', style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateY(0)' }))
])


query('h1,.mt-2,p', ...), worked great! Thank you!

@tlaukkan grat to hear, although I would suggest you give them a specific targeting class or attribute, like <div class="__animate"> or <div animated> (for respective queries query('.__animate') & query('[animated]')

Perfect! I will add this to my code. I appreciate your help! :)

No problem, if it resolved your issue be sure to accept the answer to close the thread !
